# When to use Hadoop, HBase, Hive and Pig?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hive, apache-pig

What are the benefits of using either **Hadoop** or **HBase** or **Hive** ?

From my understanding, **HBase** avoids using map-reduce and has a column oriented storage on top of HDFS. **Hive** is a sql-like interface for **Hadoop** and **HBase**.

I would also like to know how **Hive** compares with **Pig**.

Comment: **Hadoop**: Hadoop Distributed File System + Computational processing model MapReduce. **HBase**: Key-Value storage, good for reading and writing in near real time. **Hive**: Used for data extraction from the HDFS using SQL-like syntax. **Pig**: is a data flow language for creating ETL.

Answer (score 366, accepted):

MapReduce is just a **computing framework**. HBase has nothing to do with it. That said, you can efficiently put or fetch data to/from HBase by writing MapReduce jobs. Alternatively you can write sequential programs using other HBase APIs, such as Java, to put or fetch the data. But we use Hadoop, HBase etc to deal with gigantic amounts of data, so that doesn't make much sense. Using normal sequential programs would be highly inefficient when your data is too huge.

Coming back to the first part of your question, Hadoop is basically 2 things: a **Distributed FileSystem (HDFS)** + a **Computation or Processing framework (MapReduce)**. Like all other FS, HDFS also provides us storage, but in a fault tolerant manner with high throughput and lower risk of data loss (because of the replication). But, being a FS, HDFS lacks **random read and write access**. This is where HBase comes into picture. It's a **distributed, scalable, big data store**, modelled after Google's BigTable. It stores data as key/value pairs.

Coming to Hive. It provides us data **warehousing** facilities on top of an existing Hadoop cluster. Along with that it provides an **SQL like** interface which makes your work easier, in case you are coming from an SQL background. You can create tables in Hive and store data there. Along with that you can even map your existing HBase tables to Hive and operate on them.

While Pig is basically a **dataflow language** that allows us to process enormous amounts of data very easily and quickly. Pig basically has 2 parts: the Pig **Interpreter** and the language, **PigLatin**. You write Pig script in PigLatin and using Pig interpreter process them. Pig makes our life a lot easier, otherwise writing MapReduce is always not easy. In fact in some cases it can really become a pain.

I had written an [article on a short comparison of different tools of the Hadoop ecosystem](http://cloudfront.blogspot.com/2013/04/hadoop-herd-when-to-use-what.html) some time ago. It's not an in depth comparison, but a short intro to each of these tools which can help you to get started.
(Just to add on to my answer. No self promotion intended)

**Both Hive and Pig queries get converted into MapReduce jobs under the hood.**

HTH

Comment: You forget to talk about `yarn` on Hadoop ecosystem :(.

Comment: Your like is dead. Can you udapte?

Answer (score 57):

I implemented a Hive Data platform recently in my firm and can speak to it in first person since I was a one man team.

## Objective

1. To have the daily web log files collected from 350+ servers daily queryable thru some **SQL** like language
2. To replace daily aggregation data generated thru *MySQL* with Hive
3. Build Custom reports thru queries in *Hive*

## Architecture Options

I benchmarked the following options:

1. **Hive+HDFS**
2. **Hive+HBase** - queries were too slow so I dumped this option

## Design

1. Daily log Files were transported to *HDFS*
2. MR jobs parsed these log files and output files in *HDFS*
3. Create Hive tables with partitions and locations pointing to *HDFS* locations
4. Create Hive query scripts (call it *HQL* if you like as diff from *SQL*) that in turn ran MR jobs in the background and generated aggregation data
5. Put all these steps into an *Oozie* workflow - scheduled with Daily *Oozie* Coordinator

## Summary

*HBase* is like a Map. If you know the key, you can instantly get the value. But if you want to know how many integer keys in Hbase are between 1000000 and 2000000 that is not suitable for *Hbase* alone.

If you have data that needs to be aggregated, rolled up, analyzed across rows then consider *Hive*.

Hopefully this helps.

*Hive* actually rocks ...I know, I have lived it for 12 months now... So does *HBase*...

Comment: HBase is a NonSQL database that stores data in HDFS. It is used when you need random, real-time read/write access to your big data.

Answer (score 30):

From Apache official website:  https://hadoop.apache.org/

> [**Hadoop**](https://hadoop.apache.org/) is a a framework that allows for the distributed processing of large data sets across clusters of computers using simple programming models.

Some more projects, which are part of Hadoop:

> - **HBase™**: A scalable, distributed database that supports structured data storage for large tables.

> - **Hive**™: A data warehouse infrastructure that provides data summarization and ad-hoc querying.

> - **Pig™**: A high-level data-flow language and execution framework for parallel computation.

**Hive Vs PIG** comparison can be found at this  SE [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356259/difference-between-pig-and-hive-why-have-both/33353322#33353322).

**HBASE** won't replace Map Reduce. **HBase** is scalable distributed database & **Map Reduce** is programming model for distributed processing of data. Map Reduce may act on data in HBASE in processing.

You can use **HIVE/HBASE** for structured/semi-structured data and process it with Hadoop Map Reduce

**Hive** should be used for analytical querying of data collected over a period of time. Few examples : Calculate trends, summarize website logs but it can't be used for real time queries.

**HBase** fits for real-time querying of Big Data.

**PIG** can be used to construct dataflows, run a scheduled jobs, crunch big volumes of data, aggregate/summarize it and store into relation database systems. It is good for ad-hoc analysis.

**Hive** can be used for ad-hoc data analysis but it can't support all un-structured data formats unlike PIG.

Comment: Facebook no longer use open source HBase for real time messaging systems. They replaced it with their in-house [Myrocks database].  (https://engineering.fb.com/core-data/migrating-messenger-storage-to-optimize-performance/)

Answer (score 23):

Consider that you work with RDBMS and have to select what to use - full table scans, or index access - but only one of them. 
If you select full table scan - use hive. If index access - HBase.

Comment: Actually you can build Hive on HBase so that you can use HQL to full scan hbase while being able to do indexed query on hbase directly. But I doubt this gives you slower performance on full scan.

Comment: HBase is write oriented system, it is not optimal on scans, although data is stored sorted. So while scanning some ranges can be good choice, full scans will be much slower then directly from HDFS

Answer (score 6):

**Understanding in depth**

**Hadoop**

`Hadoop` is an open source project of the `Apache` foundation. It is a framework written in `Java`, originally developed by Doug Cutting in 2005. It was created to support distribution for `Nutch`, the text search engine. `Hadoop` uses Google's `Map Reduce` and Google File System Technologies as its foundation.

**Features of Hadoop**

1. It is optimized to handle massive quantities of structured, semi-structured and unstructured data using commodity hardware.
2. It has shared nothing architecture.
3. It replicates its data into multiple computers so that if one goes down, the data can still be processed from another machine that stores its replica.
4. `Hadoop` is for high throughput rather than low latency. It is a batch operation handling massive quantities of data; therefore the response time is not immediate.
5. It complements Online Transaction Processing and Online Analytical Processing. However, it is not a replacement for a `RDBMS`.
6. It is not good when work cannot be parallelized or when there are dependencies within the data.
7. It is not good for processing small files. It works best with huge data files and data sets.

**Versions of Hadoop**

There are two versions of `Hadoop` available :

1. Hadoop 1.0
2. Hadoop 2.0

**Hadoop 1.0**

It has two main parts :

**1. Data Storage Framework**

It is a general-purpose file system called Hadoop Distributed File System (`HDFS`).

`HDFS` is schema-less

It simply stores data files and these data files can be in just about any format.

The idea is to store files as close to their original form as possible.

This in turn provides the business units and the organization the much needed flexibility and agility without being overly worried by what it can implement.

**2. Data Processing Framework**

This is a simple functional programming model initially popularized by Google as `MapReduce`.

It essentially uses two functions: `MAP` and `REDUCE` to process data.

The "Mappers" take in a set of key-value pairs and generate intermediate data (which is another list of key-value pairs).

The "Reducers" then act on this input to produce the output data.

The two functions seemingly work in isolation with one another, thus enabling the processing to be highly distributed in highly parallel, fault-tolerance and scalable way.

**Limitations of Hadoop 1.0**

1. The first limitation was the requirement of `MapReduce` programming expertise.
2. It supported only batch processing which although is suitable for tasks such as log analysis, large scale data mining projects but pretty much unsuitable for other kinds of projects.
3. One major limitation was that `Hadoop 1.0` was tightly computationally coupled with `MapReduce`, which meant that the established data management vendors where left with two opinions:

   1. Either rewrite their functionality in `MapReduce` so that it could be 
      executed in `Hadoop` or
   2. Extract data from `HDFS` or process it outside of `Hadoop`.

None of the options were viable as it led to process inefficiencies caused by data being moved in and out of the `Hadoop` cluster.

**Hadoop 2.0**

In `Hadoop 2.0`, `HDFS` continues to be data storage framework.

However, a new and seperate resource management framework called **Y**et **A**nother **R**esource **N**egotiater (**YARN**) has been added.

Any application capable of dividing itself into parallel tasks is supported by YARN.

YARN coordinates the allocation of subtasks of the submitted application, thereby further enhancing the flexibility, scalability and efficiency of applications.

It works by having an **Application Master** in place of **Job Tracker**, running applications on resources governed by new **Node Manager**.

ApplicationMaster is able to run any application and not just `MapReduce`.

This means it does not only support batch processing but also real-time processing. `MapReduce` is no longer the only data processing option.

**Advantages of Hadoop**

It stores data in its native from. There is no structure imposed while keying in data or storing data. `HDFS` is schema less. It is only later when the data needs to be processed that the structure is imposed on the raw data.

It is scalable. `Hadoop` can store and distribute very large datasets across hundreds of inexpensive servers that operate in parallel.

It is resilient to failure. `Hadoop` is fault tolerance. It practices replication of data diligently which means whenever data is sent to any node, the same data also gets replicated to other nodes in the cluster, thereby ensuring that in event of node failure,there will always be another copy of data available for use.

It is flexible. One of the key advantages of `Hadoop` is that it can work with any kind of data: structured, unstructured or semi-structured. Also, the processing is extremely fast in `Hadoop` owing to the "move code to data" paradigm.

**Hadoop Ecosystem**

Following are the components of `Hadoop` ecosystem:

**HDFS**: `Hadoop` Distributed File System. It simply stores data files as close to the original form as possible.

**HBase**: It is Hadoop's database and compares well with an `RDBMS`. It supports structured data storage for large tables.

**Hive**: It enables analysis of large datasets using a language very similar to standard `ANSI SQL`, which implies that anyone familier with `SQL` should be able to access data on a `Hadoop` cluster.

**Pig**: It is an easy to understand data flow language. It helps with analysis of large datasets which is quite the order with `Hadoop`. `Pig` scripts are automatically converted to `MapReduce` jobs by the `Pig` interpreter.

**ZooKeeper**: It is a coordination service for distributed applications.

**Oozie**: It is a workflow `schedular` system to manage Apache `Hadoop` jobs.

**Mahout**: It is a scalable machine learning and data mining library.

**Chukwa**: It is data collection system for managing large distributed system.

**Sqoop**: It is used to transfer bulk data between `Hadoop` and structured data stores such as relational databases.

**Ambari**: It is a web based tool for provisioning, managing and monitoring `Hadoop` clusters.

**Hive**

`Hive` is a data warehouse infrastructure tool to process structured data in `Hadoop`. It resides on top of `Hadoop` to summarize Big Data and makes querying and analyzing easy.

**Hive is not**

1. A relational database
2. A design for Online Transaction Processing (`OLTP`).
3. A language for real-time queries and row-level updates.

**Features of Hive**

1. It stores schema in database and processed data into `HDFS`.
2. It is designed for `OLAP`.
3. It provides `SQL` type language for querying called `HiveQL` or `HQL`.
4. It is familier, fast, scalable and extensible.

**Hive Architecture**

The following components are contained in Hive Architecture:

1. **User Interface**: `Hive` is a `data warehouse` infrastructure that can create interaction between user and `HDFS`. The User Interfaces that `Hive` supports are Hive Web UI, Hive Command line and Hive HD Insight(In Windows Server).
2. **MetaStore**: `Hive` chooses respective `database` `servers` to store the schema or `Metadata` of tables, databases, columns in a table, their data types and `HDFS` mapping.
3. **HiveQL Process Engine**: `HiveQL` is similar to `SQL` for querying on schema info on the `Metastore`. It is one of the replacements of traditional approach for `MapReduce` program. Instead of writing `MapReduce` in `Java`, we can write a query for `MapReduce` and process it.
4. **Exceution Engine**: The conjunction part of `HiveQL` process engine and `MapReduce` is the `Hive` Execution Engine. Execution engine processes the query and generates results as same as `MapReduce results`. It uses the flavor of `MapReduce`.
5. **HDFS or HBase**: `Hadoop` Distributed File System or `HBase` are the data storage techniques to store data into file system.

Answer (score 5):

For a Comparison Between Hadoop Vs Cassandra/HBase read this [post](http://shazsterblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/hadoop-vs-cassandra-and-hbase.html).

Basically HBase enables really fast read and writes with scalability. How fast and scalable? [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/UsingHbase) uses it to manage its user statuses, photos, chat messages etc. HBase is so fast sometimes stacks have been developed by Facebook to use HBase as the data store for Hive itself.

Where As Hive is more like a Data Warehousing solution. You can use a syntax similar to SQL to query Hive contents which results in a Map Reduce job. Not ideal for fast, transactional systems.

Answer (score 5):

I worked on Lambda architecture processing Real time and Batch loads. 
Real time processing is needed where fast decisions need to be taken in case of Fire alarm send by sensor or fraud detection in case of banking transactions.
Batch processing is needed to summarize data which can be feed into BI systems.

we used **Hadoop** ecosystem technologies for above applications.

**Real Time Processing**

Apache Storm: Stream Data processing, Rule application

HBase: Datastore for serving Realtime dashboard

**Batch Processing**
Hadoop:  Crunching huge chunk of data. 360 degrees overview or adding context to events. Interfaces or frameworks like Pig, MR, Spark, Hive, Shark help in computing. This layer needs scheduler for which Oozie is good option.

**Event Handling layer**

Apache Kafka was first layer to consume high velocity events from sensor. 
Kafka serves both Real Time and Batch analytics data flow through Linkedin connectors.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we should get clear that **Hadoop** was created as a faster alternative to **RDBMS**. To process large amount of data at a very fast rate which earlier took a lot of time in RDBMS.

Now one should know the two terms :

1. **Structured Data** : This is the data that we used in traditional RDBMS and is divided into well defined structures.
2. **Unstructured Data** : This is important to understand, about 80% of the world data is unstructured or semi structured. These are the data which are on its raw form and cannot be processed using RDMS. Example : facebook, twitter data. (http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/unstructured-data-in-a-big-data-environment.html).

*So, large amount of data was being generated in the last few years and the data was mostly unstructured, that gave birth to HADOOP. It was mainly used for very large amount of data that takes unfeasible amount of time using RDBMS. It had many drawbacks, that it could not be used for comparatively small data in real time but they have managed to remove its drawbacks in the newer version.*

*Before going further I would like to tell that a new Big Data tool is created when they see a fault on the previous tools. So, whichever tool you will see that is created has been done to overcome the problem of the previous tools.*

**Hadoop** can be simply said as two things : **Mapreduce** and **HDFS**. Mapreduce is where the processing takes place and HDFS is the DataBase where data is stored. This structure followed **WORM** principal i.e. write once read multiple times. So, once we have stored data in HDFS, we cannot make changes. This led to the creation of **HBASE**, a NOSQL product where we can make changes in the data also after writing it once.

*But with time we saw that Hadoop had many faults and for that we created different environment over the Hadoop structure. PIG and HIVE are two popular examples.*

**HIVE** was created for people with **SQL** background. The queries written is similar to SQL named as **HIVEQL**. HIVE was developed to process completely **structured data**. It is not used for ustructured data.

**PIG** on the other hand has its own query language i.e. **PIG LATIN**. It can be used for both **structured** as well as **unstructured data**.

Moving to the difference as when to use HIVE and when to use PIG, I don't think anyone other than the architect of PIG could say. Follow the link :
https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/comparing-pig-latin-sql-constructing-data-processing-pipelines-444.html

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer in few words.

Hadoop is an eco-system which comprises of all other tools. So, you can't compare Hadoop but you can compare MapReduce.

Here are my few cents:

1. **Hive:** If your need is very SQLish meaning your problem statement can be catered by SQL, then the easiest thing to do would be to use Hive. The other case, when you would use hive is when you want a server to have certain structure of data.
2. **Pig:** If you are comfortable with Pig Latin and you need is more of the data pipelines. Also, your data lacks structure. In those cases, you could use Pig. Honestly there is not much difference between Hive & Pig with respect to the use cases.
3. **MapReduce:** If your problem can not be solved by using SQL straight, you first should try to create UDF for Hive & Pig and then if the UDF is not solving the problem then getting it done via MapReduce makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Pig:  it is better to handle files and cleaning data
  example:  removing null values,string handling,unnecessary values
Hive: for querying on cleaned data

Answer (score 0):

1.We are using Hadoop for storing Large data (i.e.structure,Unstructure and Semistructure data ) in the form file format like txt,csv.

2.If We want columnar Updations in our data then we are using Hbase tool

3.In case of Hive , we are storing Big data which is in structured format 
and in addition to that we are providing Analysis on that data.

4.Pig is tool which is using Pig latin language to analyze data which is in any format(structure,semistructure and unstructure).

Answer (score 0):

Cleansing Data in Pig is very easy,a suitable approach would be cleansing data through pig and then processing data through hive and later uploading it to hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

Use of Hive, Hbase and Pig w.r.t. my real time experience in different projects.

Hive is used mostly for:

- Analytics purpose where you need to do analysis on history data
- Generating business reports based on certain columns
- Efficiently managing the data together with metadata information
- Joining tables on certain columns which are frequently used by using bucketing concept
- Efficient Storing and querying using partitioning concept
- Not useful for transaction/row level operations like update, delete, etc.

Pig is mostly used for:

- Frequent data analysis on huge data
- Generating aggregated values/counts on huge data
- Generating enterprise level key performance indicators very frequently

Hbase is mostly used:

- For real time processing of data
- For efficiently managing Complex and nested schema
- For real time querying and faster result
- For easy Scalability with columns
- Useful for transaction/row level operations like update, delete, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to this question is -

Hadoop - Is Framework which facilitates distributed file system and programming model which allow us to store humongous sized data and process data in distributed fashion very efficiently and with very less processing time compare to traditional approaches.

(HDFS - Hadoop Distributed File system)
(Map Reduce - Programming Model for distributed processing)

Hive - Is query language which allows to read/write data from Hadoop distributed file system in a very popular SQL like fashion. This made life easier for many non-programming background people as they don't have to write Map-Reduce program anymore except for very complex scenarios where Hive is not supported.

Hbase - Is Columnar NoSQL Database. Underlying storage layer for Hbase is again HDFS. Most important use case for this database is to be able to store billion's of rows with million's of columns. Low latency feature of Hbase helps faster and random access of record over distributed data, is very important feature to make it useful for complex projects like Recommender Engines. Also it's record level versioning capability allow user to store transactional data very efficiently (this solves the problem of updating records we have with HDFS and Hive)

Hope this is helpful to quickly understand the above 3 features.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this thread hasn't done in particular justice to HBase and Pig in particular. While I believe Hadoop is the choice of the distributed, resilient file-system for big-data lake implementations, the choice between HBase and Hive is in particular well-segregated.

As in, a lot of use-cases have a particular requirement of SQL like or No-SQL like interfaces. With Phoenix on top of HBase, though SQL like capabilities is certainly achievable, however, the performance, third-party integrations, dashboard update are a kind of painful experiences. However, it's an excellent choice for databases requiring horizontal scaling.

Pig is in particular excellent for non-recursive batch like computations or ETL pipelining (somewhere, where it outperforms Spark by a comfortable distance). Also, it's high-level dataflow implementations is an excellent choice for batch querying and scripting. The choice between Pig and Hive is also pivoted on the need of the client or server-side scripting, required file formats, etc. Pig supports Avro file format which is not true in the case of Hive. The choice for 'procedural dataflow language' vs 'declarative data flow language' is also a strong argument for the choice between pig and hive.

Answer (score 0):

> Hadoop:

HDFS stands for Hadoop Distributed File System which uses  Computational processing model Map-Reduce.

> HBase:

HBase is Key-Value storage, good for reading and writing in near real time.

> Hive:

Hive is used for data extraction from the HDFS using SQL-like syntax. Hive use HQL language.

> Pig:

Pig is a data flow language for creating ETL. It's an scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

Pig is mostly dead after Cloudera got rid of it in CDP. Also last release on Apache was 19 June, 2017: release 0.17.0 so basically no committers actively working anymore. Use Spark or Python way more powerful than Pig.